# Python/SKlearn: Using KFold Results in big ROC_AUC Variations

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc, auc

Based on data that our business department supplied to us, I used the sklearn decision tree algorithm to determine the `ROC_AUC` for a binary classification problem.

The data consists of 450 rows and there are 30 features in the data.

I used 10 times StratifiedKFold repetition/split of training and test data. As a result, I got the following ROC_AUC values:

```
0.624
0.594
0.522
0.623
0.585
0.656
0.629
0.719
0.589
0.589
0.592
```

As I am new in machine learning, I am unsure whether such a variation in the ROC_AUC values can be expected (with minimum values of 0.522 and maximum values of 0.719).

My questions are:

1. Is such a big variation to be expected?
2. Could it be reduced with more data (=rows)?
3. Will the ROC_AUC variance get smaller, if the ROC_AUC gets better ("closer to 1")?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do k-fold splits to actually evaluate how well your model generalizes.

Therefore, from your current results I would assume the following:

- This is a difficult problem, the AUCs are usually low.
- 0.71 is an outlier, you were just lucky there (probably).

Important questions that will help us help you:

- What is the proportion of the binary classes? Are they balanced?
- What are the features? Are they all continuous? If categorical, are they ordinal or nominal?
- Why Decision Tree? Have you tried other methods? Logistic Regression for instance is a good start before you move on to more advanced ML methods.
- You should run more iterations, instead of k fold use the ShuffleSplit function and run at least 100 iterations, compute the Average AUC with 95% Confidence Intervals. That will give you a better idea of how well the models perform.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! 1) The proportion of the binary class values is `true/false` = `1/2`. 2) There is a mix of continuous / ordinal / nominal features. 3) I have tried 8 other algorithms. Decision Tree performs best (with StratifiedKFold). 4) Now I am experimenting with KFold, ShuffleSplit and StratifiedShuffleSplit.

Comment: Ok, so there is some unbalance in your data. I would advise you to check if the classifiers you are using have the property class_weight, and then set it to "balanced". Also Do some RandomGridSearch to find the best parameters for your classifier (do it on the training data though, to avoid overfitting). Continuous and ordinal can be put together without pre-processing, but if the nominal has more than 2 categories than you should One-hot encode them, to make sure the distance between the classes is kept the same.

Comment: Finally some ML methods, like the SVM, are affected by the scale of the features, so consider using some normalization or standardization for your data. All these functions are available at sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

> Is such a big variation to be expected?

This is a textbook case of [high variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff).

Depending on the difficulty of your problem, 405 training samples may not be enough for it to generalize properly, and the random forest may be too powerful.
Try adding some regularization, by limiting the number of splits that the trees are allowed to make. This should reduce the variance in your model, though you might expect a potentially lower average performance.

> Could it be reduced with more data (=rows)?

Yes, adding data is the other popular way of lowering the variance of your model. If you're familiar with deep learning, you'll know that deep models usually need LOTS of samples to learn properly. That's because they are very powerful models with an intrinsically high variance, and therefore a lot of data is needed for them to generalize.

> Will the ROC_AUC variance get smaller, if the ROC_AUC gets better ("closer to 1")?

Variance will decrease with regularization and adding data, it has no relation to the actual performance "number" that you get.

Cheers